# Selectively batch copy files

Tags: rsync, scp, batch-jobs

I've got a directory containing these files:

```
RG000909-A1_1.jpg
RG000909-A2_1.jpg
RG000909-A3_1.jpg
RG000909-A4_1.jpg
RG000909-A5_1.jpg   
RG000909-A6_1.jpg
RG000909-A7_1.jpg
RG000909-A8_1.jpg
RG000909-A9_1.jpg
RG000909-A10_1.jpg
RG000909-B1_1.jpg
RG000909-B2_1.jpg
RG000909-B3_1.jpg
RG000909-B4_1.jpg
RG000909-B5_1.jpg
RG000909-B6_1.jpg
RG000909-B7_1.jpg
RG000909-B8_1.jpg
RG000909-B9_1.jpg
RG000909-B10_1.jpg
RG000909-C1_1.jpg
RG000909-C2_1.jpg
RG000909-C3_1.jpg
RG000909-C4_1.jpg
RG000909-C5_1.jpg
RG000909-C6_1.jpg
RG000909-C7_1.jpg
RG000909-C8_1.jpg
RG000909-C9_1.jpg
RG000909-C10_1.jpg
RG000909-D1_1.jpg
RG000909-D2_1.jpg
RG000909-D3_1.jpg
RG000909-D4_1.jpg
RG000909-D5_1.jpg
RG000909-D6_1.jpg
RG000909-D7_1.jpg
RG000909-D8_1.jpg
RG000909-D9_1.jpg
RG000909-D10_1.jpg
RG000909-E1_1.jpg
RG000909-E2_1.jpg
RG000909-E3_1.jpg
RG000909-E4_1.jpg
RG000909-E5_1.jpg
RG000909-E6_1.jpg
RG000909-E7_1.jpg
RG000909-E8_1.jpg
RG000909-E9_1.jpg
RG000909-E10_1.jpg
RG000909-F1_1.jpg
RG000909-F2_1.jpg
RG000909-F3_1.jpg
RG000909-F4_1.jpg
RG000909-F5_1.jpg
RG000909-F6_1.jpg
RG000909-F7_1.jpg
RG000909-F8_1.jpg
RG000909-F9_1.jpg
RG000909-F10_1.jpg
RG000909-G1_1.jpg
RG000909-G2_1.jpg
RG000909-G3_1.jpg
RG000909-G4_1.jpg 
RG000909-G5_1.jpg
RG000909-G6_1.jpg
RG000909-G7_1.jpg
RG000909-G8_1.jpg
RG000909-G9_1.jpg
RG000909-G10_1.jpg
RG000909-H1_1.jpg
RG000909-H2_1.jpg
RG000909-H3_1.jpg
RG000909-H4_1.jpg
RG000909-H5_1.jpg
RG000909-H6_1.jpg
RG000909-H7_1.jpg
RG000909-H8_1.jpg
RG000909-H9_1.jpg
RG000909-H10_1.jpg
```

What single command could I use to copy out

1)

```
RG000909-A1_1.jpg
RG000909-A2_1.jpg
RG000909-A3_1.jpg
RG000909-A4_1.jpg
RG000909-A5_1.jpg
RG000909-B1_1.jpg
RG000909-B2_1.jpg
RG000909-B3_1.jpg
RG000909-B4_1.jpg
RG000909-B5_1.jpg
RG000909-C1_1.jpg
RG000909-C2_1.jpg
RG000909-C3_1.jpg
RG000909-C4_1.jpg
RG000909-C5_1.jpg
RG000909-D1_1.jpg
RG000909-D2_1.jpg
RG000909-D3_1.jpg
RG000909-D4_1.jpg
RG000909-D5_1.jpg
RG000909-E1_1.jpg
RG000909-E2_1.jpg
RG000909-E3_1.jpg
RG000909-E4_1.jpg
RG000909-E5_1.jpg
RG000909-F1_1.jpg
RG000909-F2_1.jpg
RG000909-F3_1.jpg
RG000909-F4_1.jpg
RG000909-F5_1.jpg
RG000909-G1_1.jpg
RG000909-G2_1.jpg
RG000909-G3_1.jpg
RG000909-G4_1.jpg 
RG000909-G5_1.jpg
RG000909-H1_1.jpg
RG000909-H2_1.jpg
RG000909-H3_1.jpg
RG000909-H4_1.jpg
RG000909-H5_1.jpg
```

or 2)

```
RG000909-A6_1.jpg
RG000909-A7_1.jpg
RG000909-A8_1.jpg
RG000909-A9_1.jpg
RG000909-A10_1.jpg
RG000909-B6_1.jpg
RG000909-B7_1.jpg
RG000909-B8_1.jpg
RG000909-B9_1.jpg
RG000909-B10_1.jpg
RG000909-C6_1.jpg
RG000909-C7_1.jpg
RG000909-C8_1.jpg
RG000909-C9_1.jpg
RG000909-C10_1.jpg
RG000909-D6_1.jpg
RG000909-D7_1.jpg
RG000909-D8_1.jpg
RG000909-D9_1.jpg
RG000909-D10_1.jpg
RG000909-E6_1.jpg
RG000909-E7_1.jpg
RG000909-E8_1.jpg
RG000909-E9_1.jpg
RG000909-E10_1.jpg
RG000909-F6_1.jpg
RG000909-F7_1.jpg
RG000909-F8_1.jpg
RG000909-F9_1.jpg
RG000909-F10_1.jpg
RG000909-G6_1.jpg
RG000909-G7_1.jpg
RG000909-G8_1.jpg
RG000909-G9_1.jpg
RG000909-G10_1.jpg
RG000909-H6_1.jpg
RG000909-H7_1.jpg
RG000909-H8_1.jpg
RG000909-H9_1.jpg
RG000909-H10_1.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp *[A-H][1-5]_*.jpg dest/
```

and

```
cp *[A-H][6-9]*.jpg *[A-H]10_*.jpg dest/
```

respectively.

For `rsync` and `scp`, the command is similar.

Comment: Hey Weijun, I also need to make *[A-H][10-12]_*.jpg work as well...but it doesnt seem to handle double digits in the second bracket very well.  Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Just use `*[A-H]1[0-2]_*.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

All file names could be generated with (in bash):

```
printf '%s/n' RG000909-{A..H}{1..10}_1.jpg
```

The list 1 will be created with

```
printf '%s/n' RG000909-{A..H}{1..5}_1.jpg
```

And list 2 will be created with:

```
printf '%s/n' RG000909-{A..H}{6..10}_1.jpg
```

The files could be copied with rsync with (list 1 as an example):

```
rsync -avz RG000909-{A..H}{1..5}_1.jpg dest/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by using combination awk,sed and cp command.Tested it worked fine

Below are commands for list1  and list2  copying into destination directory

Destination directory and source directory  You need to specify in the command

For list1

---

```
 ls -ltr sourcedirectory_path |sed -n '/RG000909-[A-H][1-5]\{1\}_/p'   | awk '{print "cp -rvfp" " " $1 " " "/Destination_directory/"}' | sh
```

For list 2

```
ls -ltr sourcedirectory_path |sed -n '/RG000909-[A-H][1-5]_/!p'   | awk '{print "cp -rvfp" " " $1 " " "/Destination_directory/"}' | sh
```